# flask with pre-trained tensorflow model

Tags: python, flask, ubuntu-16.04, tensorflow

is there a way to use pre-trained char-lstm tensorflow with GPU (1.2) model within flask (0.12.2) app?

Model functions seamlessly when started through shell. I'm loading it with the following code below (without initializing tf variables, placeholders or similar):

```
....

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    saver.restore(sess, SAVE_PATH)
....
```

When trying to load the same pre-trained model (with 3 files: `.meta`, `.index` & `.data`) through Flask it throws

> ValueError: No variables to save

Is there a way to make it work? Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you need to initialize and use your variables properly.

Here's the simplest example I could find:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create TensorFlow object called hello_constant
hello_constant = tf.constant('Hello World!')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the tf.constant operation in the session
    output = sess.run(hello_constant)
    print(output)
```

A more complex example that could be more useful for you is:

```
def model_inputs():
    """
    Create TF Placeholders for input, targets, learning rate, and lengths of source and target sequences.
    :return: Tuple (input, targets, learning rate, keep probability, target sequence length,
    max target sequence length, source sequence length)
    """
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,None],name='input')
    target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,None])
    target_sequence_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='target_sequence_length')
    max_target_len = tf.reduce_max(target_sequence_len,name='max_target_length' )
    source_sequence_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='source_sequence_length')
    learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
    return input, target, learning_rate, keep_prob, target_sequence_len, max_target_len, source_sequence_len
```

And here's how to make the variables available in the session

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

The topic is **important** and I find it hard to summarize it efficiently in a single StackOverflow reply.
If you want a deeper look in how the system works I'd suggest to read the [TensorFlow documentation about variables.](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)

Comment: Thanks @Pitto for the response. Still I'm not getting the reason why it works in shell and in flask doesn't. Also, can you pls confirm that it's no problem that:
- Model has auto generated node names
- Model is not friezed

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?
If you've found my answer useful please accept it / upvote :)